# Nginx load balancer to serve static files from multiple WSGI servers

Tags: linux, devops

So I have recently been learning more about Nginx. I used it before to serve one web app on the same system but want to scale out separately. I have been able to setup an Nginx load balancer with 2 Gunicorn servers running my Flask app. My question is how to set it up to use Nginx's static serving abilities from each of these Gunicorn servers.

Lets say I have 3 Virtual Private Servers I am am paying for. number 1 has Nginx as a load balancer/reverse proxy routing requests to number 2 and number 3 which are duplicate web apps. I want these to be stand alone with everything they need to run the app, including their static directories. So instead of having a static directory on the load balancer/reverse proxy it is all contained in the web app directory structure.

Currently it looks like this:

```
                                  Gunicorn -> Flask
                                /
Nginx loadbalancer/reverseproxy 
                                \
                                  Gunicorn -> Flask
```

Do I need to put Nginx on each Gunicorn server to access the static dir and return the static files to the Nginx loadbalancer/reverseproxy? So as follows:

```
                                  Nginx -> Gunicorn -> Flask
                                /
Nginx loadbalancer/reverseproxy 
                                \
                                  Nginx -> Gunicorn -> Flask
```

Maybe I am doing this all wrong and the above is overkill and may not increase performance. If so what is a good structure for load balancing and caching on one main entry point and routing to Gunicorn with the ability to serve static files with so Gunicorn doesn't have to?

What I really want is to be able to have a server with everything for the Web App installed so I can easily add more as needed and just point the load balancer to these upstream servers.

Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I will checkout your suggestion. I would contest that deployment fits in with development. After all your web app is nothing with out a web server. Yes mine was a bit specific on static content(css, javascript, html content) which is all code.

Comment: Asd you can see I answer many Anaconda related question from troubleshooting to configuration which have nothing to do with programming  but is a piece of software for package management. Those questions don't seem to get voted down.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this would be on production, and as far as my understanding of gunicorn takes me, you should not use unicorn itself to serve static files,

At the end of the day the nginx at the front of the whole system would act just as a load balancer/rev proxy, you could configure that server to just distribute the incoming requests to a set of upstream servers,

Now, regarding the upstream servers, the would go just like this

```
Nginx -> Gunicorn -> Flask
```

Where its configuration would make certain requests be served from the static file directory and others go straight to the gunicorn server,

At the end of the day you would deploy discrete upstream servers to the pool and add them to the rev proxy conf, so it would look like this (just as you mentioned)

```
                                  Nginx -> Gunicorn -> Flask
                                /
Nginx loadbalancer/reverseproxy 
                                \
                                  Nginx -> Gunicorn -> Flask
```

Be aware that each server could be deployed on its own and has the capacity of server the whole site on its own,

This answer comes from the fact that you cannot really serve static files from other backend hosts if not going through a server itself and since nginx is literally one of the best things out there on that task, it makes sense to use it.

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation. This was where my thoughts were leading me to. So in this setup I assuming I should handle caching on the load balancer/reverse proxy at the front to save on requests to the upstream servers. does that sound right?

Comment: i don't really know much about what would you gain in performance, and it heavily depends on the type of application you are developing,  but nginx actually provides a native caching mechanism that would help you implement a cache-through schema with the proxy_cache directive. Again, bear in mind what you want to cache and how it makes sense to cache it (policies to deem the cache stale, etc...). You can even set it to serve cached data in case the rest of your infrastructure is down!